# Plot map in R - center and move labels: x.coords and y.coords

Tags: r, plot

I am new in R and I want to plot a map,  but I am not able to center and move the label of "y.coords" I have tried this code

```
 clab = 0.8
 cmain = 2
 caxis = 0.8
 par(mar=c(4,3,1,1), mgp=c(3, 1, 0), las=1)
 plot(p1,asp=1, main= "AM - Pico", xlab="x.coords", 
 ylab="y.coords",cex.axis=caxis)
 #mtext ("y.coords", 1, 1.5)
 points(AcaciaP,cex=0.5,pch = 20)
 axis(1,at = seq (365000,415000,5000))
 axis(2,at = seq (4245000,4275000,5000),pos=365000)
```

Comment: Consider providing reproducible data for people to work with (e.g., we don't have access to your `p1`).

Answer (score 0):

The following changes should help you to modify your plot:

Add cex.axis argument, so you could change the font size in your axis() function

```
par(mar=c(4,3,1,1), mgp=c(3, 1, 0), las=1, cex.axis=caxis)
```

Probably remove `asp` argument (though it might work for your dataset), remove `cex.axis` argument as you plot axis separately and add axes=TRUE to display axes later with `axes()` function

```
plot(p1,main= "AM - Pico", xlab="x.coords", 
     ylab="y.coords",cex.axis=caxis, axes=FALSE)
```